# Ajax Checkbox that submit with prevent click upon post/submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

Hi I'm working on an ajax function in jquery that saves the value of a checkbox. Here is my question, What if the user clicks in multiple times even the saving is not yet finished/success? How can i Prevent the user to tick the checkbox when the form is submitting? Thanks !

Heres my Code Snippet:

```
$(".chkOverride").click(function (e) {
            var userId = $("#UserId").val();
            var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked")
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Worker/Worker?Id=" + Id + "&isChecked=" + isChecked + "&UserId=" + UserId,
                type: "post",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("Success!");
                    location.reload();

                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable the checkbox before starting the ajax call. You may use the `prop()` method to do that. Set the `disabled` property value to true

```
$(".chkOverride").click(function (e) {

      var _this=$(this);
      _this.prop('disabled', true);

      var userId = $("#UserId").val();
      var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked")
      $.ajax({
                url: "/Worker/Worker?Id=" + Id + "&isChecked=" + 
                                                       isChecked + "&UserId=" + UserId,
                type: "post",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("Success!");
                   //No point in enabling as you are going to reload the page
                   _this.prop('disabled', false);
                    location.reload();

                },
                error: function () {
                  alert("Error :(");
                   _this.prop('disabled', false);
                }
          });
});
```

Comment: so if i remove that page reload, i should add the disabled false property

Comment: Yes. that will remove the disabled behavior from the element.

Answer (score 2):

Have you come across this link:

[Inhibit a checkbox from changing when clicking it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191056/inhibit-a-checkbox-from-changing-when-clicking-it)

You can disable the checkbox using

```
$this.attr('disabled', 1);
```

Disable the button before making the Ajax call.